# How to populate a PDF form such as a w-2 from data inside of the the database?

Tags: php, pdf, fdf

i have a w-2 form and other pdf documents and using adobe acrobat pro i have created fields with field names using the adobe application. how do i populate those fields? i have done this a few years ago where the php would generate the fdf file then load the pdf file and populate it but i completly forgot how i did it. any help would be great. thanks

Answer (score 0):

The following links might help you get started.  You only need to supply the data from a database rather than HTML forms:

- [Forms Data Format](http://us.php.net/fdf)
- [Using HTML forms to fill in PDF fields with PHP and FDF](http://koivi.com/fill-pdf-form-fields/)

Answer (score 0):

Google found me this:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/FillFormFieldsOfPDFs.aspx

PDF (W-4) filled in with above tool
[image]

Does it fit your needs? (C#)